# soffice not found, even though libreoffice buildpack is installed - heroku server

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, libreoffice

I am using a npm package called libreoffice-convert which needs libre office installed to work. I have installed the libre office build pack on the heroku server where this node app is deployed however whenever I try and run this package I still an get `Error: Could not find soffice binary`